# Discard changes confirm on program exit if richtextbox content changed

Tags: c#, dialog, richtextbox, messagebox, notepad

I would like to ask the user when he/she clicks the closebutton: save the file, discard the changes, or go back IF the RichTextBox content changed. Like Windows Notepad or any other text editor does. How could I do that?

Comment: Great. Do so. You have our approval.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. We will help you fix it.

Comment: I tried searching, didn't get anything that would work. It just simply didn't work. It looks like nobody asked a this kind of question. Because I want it to only pop up if the textbox content changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [read about events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx) and how they work.  In this case, you are interested in the `TextChanged` event of the `RichTextBox` and the `FormClosing` event of the form.

[TextChanged Event : MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

The `TextChanged` event is raised whenever the contents of the textbox are modified.  One way to track changes in the textbox is simply to use a boolean value.  Be sure to set it to `false` when you are loading data into the textbox.  Then, when the user changes the text the `TextChanged` event will fire and you can set the `_textChanged` (in the example below) value to `true`.

Similarly, making use of the `FormClosing` event allows you to react to a user attempting to close the form.

[FormClosing Event : MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

This event passes a `FormClosingEventArgs` value `e` that allows you to cancel the closing of the form (in this case if the user selects to cancel when prompted about the text having been changed).  It also allows you to perform any other action before the form is closed.

To create the message dialog you can use an appropriate overload of `MessageBox.Show` - this function returns a `DialogResult` indicating which of the buttons the user clicked.  This allows you to take different actions depending on the selection the user made.

[MessageBox.Show : MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

If you don't know how to connect these events, then I suggest you read through s[ome of the basic documentation and examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43sxkdeb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).  This is pretty elementary stuff that you will need to understand to get much of anything done in C#.  The examples here are winforms since you have not indicated otherwise.

This is a trivial example :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{ 
    private bool _textChanged;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
       // load data to richtextbox, then ....
        _textChanged = false;
    }

    private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _textChanged = true;
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_textChanged)
        {
            DialogResult rslt = MessageBox.Show("save changes?", "some caption",
                               MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);
            if (rslt == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                // save changes and exit
            }
            else if (rslt == DialogResult.Cancel)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                // cancel close, return to form
            }
            // else do not save and continue closing form
        }
    }
}
```